# Google Forms-like form creator with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, mongodb

I'm trying to create a Rails app where our organization's users can create forms and then let our customers answer them in our website.

In short the requirements are:

- Drag-and-drop form creation interface;
- Conditional redirection (ex: if customer answers yes to a certain question, redirect to form x, else redirect to form y);
- Client and server-side validation of fields, established by the users, whenever possible;
- Associate answers with a "customer" entity (also notice the fields in these answers aren't pre-established in the model/DB);
- Customization is a plus (ex: custom classes for the fields), users are tech-savvy.

So far I've been using https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder to provide the actual form-building, but I've been having some problems with encoding (our forms have a lot of á, ã, à and such) and it generates an XML, which sometimes doesn't play nice when I try to render the form later; maybe if I could serialize/de-serialize it the later (or both, who knows) wouldn't be a problem anymore.

I'm also using MongoDB to store the answers and manually setting the redirections based on the answers (not cool).

So, is there a Rails/JS/dunno framework with which I could streamline all these actions (or at least some of them)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding issue should be solved in v1.15.0 of formBuilder https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder/pull/211. I also wrote another plug-in called Formeo http://draggable.github.io/formeo/ that uses JSON and handles special characters pretty well.

Unfortunately I don't know of any package that handles the full front and back of a form building app other than the one I'm building, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: formBuilder now also supports JSON data with option `dataType` set to `'json'`